# Good reduction of finite etale covers of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Let $R$ be a dvr (whose residue characteristic is zero if it helps) with fraction field $K$.
Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $K$ with good reduction over $R$. Let $X\to A$ be a finite etale morphism with $X$ geometrically connected over $K$.

> > Does $X$ have good reduction over $R$? (That is, does $X$ have a smooth proper model over $R$?)

By Lang-Neron, there is finite field extension $L/K$ such that    $X$ is an abelian variety over $K$. In this case  $X\to A$ is an isogeny and it follows from Neron-Ogg-Shafarevich that $X$ has good reduction as well over $R$. Thus, $X$ has potential good reduction over $R$, i.e., there is a finite extension $L/K$ such that $X_{R_L}$ has a smooth proper model over $R_L$, where $R_L$ is the integral closure of $R$ in $L$.

I fear that my answer has a negative answer, but I can't think of an explicit example. Can one find an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with good reduction at a prime $p$, an $E$-torsor $T$ with bad reduction at this prime $p$,  and a finite etale cover $T\to E$. But I do not see how.

Comment: Try the cover of $y^2=x^3-x$ given by $z^2=3x$ with $p=3$.

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused. By $z^2=3x$ you mean a projective quadratic curve of genus $0$? How to cover a genus $1$ curve by another of genus $0$?